# Microsoft OneNote 2010 - How do you move the Page Title?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, title

Basically, as the title states... when you create a page in OneNote, I'm just looking to move the Title of the page from where it normally is to somewhere else... any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly clunky way to do this: Add an image to your page, and move/resize it so that the left/top edge is outside the visible bounds of the page. Right click the picture and choose "Set image as background." OneNote will resize the page to accommodate the entire image, but will not adjust the position of the title, effectively moving the title down/right.  You can then remove the background and the title will stay where it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can just move it to the right side if you are using RTL language.
Otherwise, I believe it is stuck on the left.

Comment: MichaelS is correct, you cannot move the Title on the page in OneNote. Do you want to do this for design/aesthetic reasons or some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

There's a really easy and simple way of doing this that works on OneNote 2016:
Cntrl alt left arrow
Ctrl alt up arrow

these two shortcuts create extra space to the left of and above the title

I don't think you can move the title freely, but you can choose where it is positioned on the page

hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the author’s question since they were using OneNote 2010.  While it’s fine to mention newer versions, it’s typically protocol, to only submit an answer that directly answers the author’s question.  So in other words, if your answer applies to OneNote 2010, it’s fine otherwise it probably should have been it’s own question/answer.  Questions are sometimes version specific.